# tSQL check if input ID is valid and if the date is in the current year

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am doing a `tSQL` assignment, and one of the requirements is to check if the inputted `charity ID` exists and if not return an error, Then I have to check If the `Tax Date` of the charity is in the current year. This is what I have tried

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT CharityID FROM CharityTbl WHERE [CharityID] = '@CharityID')
begin
  raiserror ('Sorry Invalid Charity ID', 16,1)
  return 99 
end
--if the TaxNoDateOfIssue for the charitytbl is not in the current year raise an error
IF NOT Exists (Select TaxNoDateOfIssue FROM CharityTbl WHERE YEAR(TaxNoDateOfIssue) = YEAR(getdate())
```

I am unsure how I should write the second if statement so any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to append the where clause in the same query. See below query.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT CharityID FROM CharityTbl WHERE [CharityID] = '@CharityID' or YEAR(TaxNoDateOfIssue) = YEAR(getdate())
begin
 raiserror ('Sorry Invalid Charity ID', 16,1)
 return 99 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Should I be using the`and` operator rather than`or` operator or does it make any difference?

Comment: You should have to use or operator in your case and will gives you wrong result.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this is the thing you are expecting.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT CharityID FROM CharityTbl WHERE [CharityID] = '@CharityID') --  fist condition
BEGIN
IF NOT Exists (Select TaxNoDateOfIssue FROM CharityTbl WHERE YEAR(TaxNoDateOfIssue) = YEAR(getdate()) -- second condition if 1st success
BEGIN
RAISERROR('Sorry Invalid Tax Year', 16,1)
RETURN 99
END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
RAISERROR('Sorry Invalid Charity ID', 16,1) --  if 1st fails
RETURN 99 
END
```

Comment: @Kevin Though both the solutions might look similar to you, but I would recommend this solution. Primary reason being, you should return an error message that signifies the correct issue. You should not return same message for two condition failures. This is one of the thumb rules a dev should follow. Rest, always depends upon how you handle error at the application end. Happy coding :)